# Missing timestamp(set) extrinsic for older blocks of statemint

Tags: data-analytics

When I need to get the timestamp of a block, I usually look for the timestamp(set) extrinsic in the block, But I realised that the older blocks(between #1 - #305203) in statemint don't seem to have the timestamp(set) extrinsic. I have 2 questions about these:

Why is the extrinsic missing?

Without the extrinsic, how can I deduce the timestamp of these blocks?

For reference here is the [subscan](https://statemint.subscan.io/block/305203) link for one of the blocks with missing extrinsic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statemint and Statemine were initially running with the `shell-runtime`. This `shell-runtime` was the most basic runtime that was possible. This means also that it didn't had the timestamp pallet and thus, it also didn't had any timestamp.